# Proving that $\ell^1$ is not complete with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification

$\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $\ell^1=\left\{x=(x_n)_n:\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\vert x_n\vert<\infty\right\}$. Prove that $\ell^1$ is not a complete metric space if we use the norm $\|x\|_2=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\vert x_n\vert^2\right)^{1/2}.$

---

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ I am going to try to use the sequence with $n$th term defined as $y_n=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\cdots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,\cdots\right).$ Then we have that $(y_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $(\ell^1,\|\cdot\|_2)$, since for $n<m$ we have that
$$\|y_m-y_n\|_2^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}<\sum^{m}_{k=n+1}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\sum^m_{k=n+1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\to0$$
as $m,n\to\infty$. Therefore, $(y_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\ell^1,\|\cdot\|_2).$ To see that $(\ell^1,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is not complete, it suffices to show that there is no $y\in\ell^1$ such that $\|y_n-y\|_2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. The latter assertion follows from the fact that $y_n\to y$ where
$$y=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\cdots\right),$$
which is not in $\ell^1$, since $\|y\|_1=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}$ is the harmonic series which diverges.
The result follows.

---

Do you agree with my proof presented above? Any comments are very welcomed and appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Yes,this is correct.